# grub high resolution wallpaper/background?

Tags: grub2

I understand that for historic and technical reasons, a standard display resolution of 640×480 was both expected and desirable for high compatibility and minimal resource usage.

As we approach a world where 16:9 or varied aspect ratio displays and high dpi or crude pixel doubling work around are becoming common place, I wanted to ask for posterity (when and) how can grub be configured with a wallpaper image larger than 1024×768?

Answer (score 2):

At time of writing, taken from the debian wiki, a grub2 wallpaper image cannot be larger than 1024×768px, and it will (configured by default) be stretched to match your gfx resolution.

One way to give the illusion of a 16:9 grub wallpaper is to take an existing 16x9 wallpaper and scale it to the 4:3 image of size 1024x768, and set the grub gfx mode for example to `GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080`, when grub loads and stretches that image its aspect ratio will appear similar to the original.

Debian wiki except from time of writing:

> ### GRUB v2 Splash Image
>
> Grub2 is ready to display a graphical screen (GRUB v1.95 is also known
>   as “version 2”, it's called grub by upstream ).
>
> Image constraints :
>
> - file format : TGA (uncompressed or RLE 1 ).
> - 640×480 pixels (you can change this, for instance 1024×768).
> - 24 and 32bits True colors : 24 bits = 16 million colors ; 32 bits = 16 million colors + 8 bits for alpha channel).
> - The text layout is fixed (including the frame).
> - Specify a black background in "set menu_color_normal", in order to make GRUB menu transparent.